# How to watch for changes in a scope variable manipulated by a service

Tags: angularjs

I need to watch for changes in a countdown variable to run a task when the time is over. 
I'm using a service to update the variable, as you can see in this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NJxqXcD2nhDKq4Q99Bgt

```
$scope.$watch('time', function (time) {
    // This portion of code is reached only twice:
    // Once when undefined and after first update.
    console.log(time);
});
```

How can I watch for every change or trigger my task from the service (despite I think this is the wrong choice)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watcher fires only twice since reference to `time` not changed. You have two options: turn on object equality (slow) or specify your own value provider:

```js
$scope.$watch('time', function () {
}, true); // Tells to check for object equality 

$scope.$watch(function () {
    return ($scope.time || {}).now;
}, function (now) {
    // magic
});
```

But i think you should consider to use `$timeout` service and promises to run task.

Comment: How do you *turn on* dirty checking?

Comment: Sorry, object equality

Comment: Oh my God, was just this (I think I was drunk):

  `$timeout(function() {
      // run task
  }, timeLeft*1000);`

Any way the question was helpful for me to learn more about `watch`.